# Import Color Theme into Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to import a custom color theme into Visual Studio Code from a JSON file. I have found a number of resources for generating and editing themes, but none of them explain how to install a theme locally. They all say to upload it to the marketplace.

Comment: build a Theme extension, create a vsix file with `vsce` and use the extension bar top menu to install the vsix file